# Use LocationListener when app is open [Android]

Tags: android, gps

I'm working on my first app, this app have 2 activity: the main activity and the second activity. Both the activity need know user location so I have create a class like this (I have edit a "internet" class):

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

boolean GPSForce = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context, Boolean forcegps) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.GPSForce = forcegps;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
...
}

public void startUsingGPS(){
    getLocation();
}

public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }

    canGetLocation = false;
}

public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingsAlert(){
...
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

On Main Activity I create an object based on GPSTracker on onCreate event then I use stopUsingGPS() on onStop event to stop GPS when the user close the application and startUsingGPS() on onResume event to restart GPS use.

My problem is this I need use GPSTracker also on second activity but with my code when second activity is open the GPS is stopped (onStop event is call also when second activity is open not onlt when the user exit from application).

I think my approachis wrong.

How can I create a GPSTracker object and to do this:
- stop GPS use only when the user exit to application;
- use it in all activity I need;

Besides I'd like trigger the change coordinates from activity but I don't know how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call stopUsingGPS() in onDestroy of MainActivity. So when user completely quits your app then only GPS Tracking will get stopped. onStop will get called each time when your activity get paused. So call stopUsingGPS() method in onDestroy of your MainActivity.

Comment: I just have try it but onDestroy is not always call when a user close the app. You can find many question about it on this site.

Comment: onDestroy will be getting called per Activity base not on app base. When user presses back button on certain activity then onDestroy of that particular activity gets called.

Comment: I this the best solution is use IBinder class like in this tutorial: http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.it/2012/05/bind-service-using-ibinder-class.html